# MMA7361 readings deviate a lot

Tags: sensors

This is what I get using a MMA7361 breakout board (just the IC, no resistors or capacitors). The IC is powered using arduino nano's 3v3 pin.

The x, y, z values are read from analog pins A0, A1, A2. The readings are subtracted with 338.

```
x   y   z 
-4 -26 44
44 -27 -5
-57 -11 27
-29 -23 22
28 -21 9
-44 3 20
-26 -14 39
26 -32 -8
-17 -12 19
-30 -15 35
4 -26 14
24 -43 49
-58 -19 0
16 -29 24
9 -48 13
-58 -42 12
12 -47 14
-24 -31 9
-46 -31 10
16 -52 1
-43 -21 8
-31 -25 16
37 -18 11
-45 -10 20
-22 -36 16
27 -19 20
-5 -9 1
-59 -10 10
37 -18 30
-53 -18 16
-30 -8 10
54 -19 17
-27 -29 15
-40 -23 -14
-1 -18 19
34 -22 2
-35 -24 41
13 -17 7
-14 -17 21
-39 -14 35
-19 -31 6
62 -9 34
-63 -16 16
-12 -6 23
60 -33 36
-45 -2 34
-18 -15 9
```

As you can see the x value, when the whole thing is not moving, can range from -59 to +44. This looks very unusual as other people's reading seems to have just +-3 deviations. What might be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (just the IC, no resistors or capacitors)
>
> What might be wrong with my setup?

That's easy: You miss the capacitors ;-)
Check figure 5 of the [datasheet](http://cache.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA7361LC.pdf) and try again.

Comment: I'm still getting +-20 of deviation with capacitors on.
Could it be wire length? Or I'm worried that I might have damaged the IC when soldering it with a torch (literally).

Comment: Wire length can be an issue. You mentioned "other people"... ask them for their schematics. Maybe they have higher capacitance for their capacitors. This will make the signals smoother, but also slower.